# solve a matrix differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve numerically a differential equation like

```
  iy'[t]=y[t]/20
```

where y is a 2*2 matrix and i is iota. 
Please suggest me a way to proceed.

Comment: To solve it numerically, you'll have to specify a number for iota and initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
M  = Array[Subscript[y, #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}];
M0 = {{1, 2}, {-6, 4}};
ci = Thread[Flatten[M] == Flatten[M0]] /. {t -> 0};

DSolve[{i D[M, t] == M/20, ci}, Variables[M], t]
```

Comment: yes, it is working. Thank you. What to do for NDSolve? How to provide the initial conditions?

Comment: Initial conditions included trough **M0**

Answer (score 1):

Alternative numerical formulations as a matrix DE:

```
ic = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}];  (* set initial condition to whatever is desired *)
Block[{i = 1},               (* set the value of i *)
 sol = NDSolve[{i y'[t] == y[t]/20, y[0] == ic}, y, {t, 0, 1}]
 ]

Block[{i = I},               (* in case i = Sqrt[-1] *)
 sol = NDSolve[{i y'[t] == y[t]/20, y[0] == ic}, y, {t, 0, 1}]
 ]
```